# Auth Middleware only works for one express route

Tags: postgresql, express

I'm trying to build my first PERN stack application and I've run into an annoying problem that I can't figure out , where my auth middleware only works for one route. I've tried creating simple test routes but it doesn't work for those either.  The middleware works perfectly fine on postman but in the browser it only works for axios.post request.

\ auth middleware

```
let auth = (req,res,next) => {
    const {token} = req.body;
  
    if(token === 'fish') {
        next();
    } else {
        res.status(403).json({message:'oops that was the wrong token!'});
    }
   
  
}
module.exports = auth;
```

\ route using express.router()

```
router.get('/test' , auth, async function(req,res) {
    res.json({message:'this is a test'})
})
```

\ frontend

```
 const TestPost = async() => {
        let url = `http://localhost:5000/post/test`;
        const data = await axios.get(url,{
            token:'fish'
        })
       
        console.log(data);
        // returns error 403(Forbidden) 
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to do a GET request, but the server is looking for data in `req.body`.  That's not how a GET request works (POST and PUT use `req.body`, not GET).  In addition: `{token: 'fish'}` is not a property that axios looks at.  For a GET request, you would need to either send the token as a custom header or as a query parameter.  Probably a custom header would be better.

Comment: And, then obviously for the GET request your server would need to look for the token where you are sending it (custom header or query parameter).